# How to properly update a array that has only one identifying id

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to update an array with objects inside something like this, with the current code I have it only saves the first one, I know that's the problem but I don't know how to fix it

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'option' => 'new',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'option' => 'ewrwer',
    ),
  ),
```

This is my current code, the line in question is

`$option = SurveyQuestionOption::where('survey_question_id', $preg->id)->first();`

How do I fix this so it cycles through all in the array `questionOptions` instead of just the first one? I tried `->get()` but then the `->save()` doesn't work.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $preg = SurveyQuestion::findOrFail($id);
    $preg->question = $request->question;
    $preg->survey_section_id = $request->survey_section_id;
    $preg->response_type_id = $request->response_type_id;
    $preg->optional = $request->optional;
    $preg->save();

    $ids = [];
    if ($request->get('questionOptions')) {
        foreach ($request->get('questionOptions') as $item) {
            $option = SurveyQuestionOption::where('survey_question_id', $preg->id)->first();

            if (empty($option)) {
                $option = new SurveyQuestionOption();
                $option->survey_question_id = $preg->id;
            }

            $option->option = $item['option'];
            $option->save();
        }
    }
    if (count($ids) > 0) {
        SurveyQuestionOption::whereNotIn('id', $ids)->where('survey_question_id', $preg->id)->delete();
        }

    DB::commit();
    return back();
}
```

Comment: Could you improve the description of the qeustion? At the momento (at least for me) it isn't very clear what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when you use get, you get a collection, so you can't really use save on it. you need to do a foreach loop, and save in that. i.e; like this;

```
$options = SurveyQuestionOption::where('survey_question_id', $preg->id)->get();
foreach($options as $option){
   if (empty($option)) {
      $option = new SurveyQuestionOption();
      $option->survey_question_id = $preg->id;
   }

   $option->option = $item['option'];
   $option->save();
}
```

Note that you can't save $options if you don't use a foreach loop, as you're not specifying which instance of the collection to save it in.